# If two normally distributed variables X and Y are correlated, how to calculate P(X > a | Y > b)?

Tags: probability, correlation, normal-distribution

For a more concrete example. Let's say that IQ is normally distributed within a population with a mean of 100 points and standard deviation of 15 points. Let's also say that a person's age-10 IQ correlates with their age-18 IQ at r = 0.75.

If we know that a given person had an IQ greater than 115 (one standard deviation above the mean) when they were 10 years old, what is the probability that they will have an IQ greater than 115 when they are 18 years old?

Comment: Use the definition of conditional probability and the joint and marginal distributions.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Two correlated normal random variables are not necessarily _jointly normal_. So how does one get the joint distribution?